# React input autoComplete prop not rendering properly

Tags: html, reactjs, autocomplete, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to specify the autoComplete attribute to "new-password" but it the autocomplete value is always "off" no matter what value I try.

My code is as follows:

```
<form>
  <input autoComplete="new-password" />
  ...
</form>
```

which the input renders as:

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

Does anyone how to specify this properly?

Note: *I am using react-bootstrap but that shouldn't have any effect since `<FormControl>` just passes the extra props to the underlying component.*

Comment: I think you need the name prop set to email. Seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95627/